# ListView to New Activity then Populate EditText's with SQLite data from Hashmap

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, hashmap

I currently have a ListView populated by SQLite and I have implemented an OnItemClickListener to list items. I want to know how to retrieve values from a Hashmap specific to the item the user clicks in the ListView, then open a new activity and populate the retrieved data into EditTexts. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT

This is what i'm guessing:

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> scanList = this.controller.getAllRecs();
            Intent intent = new Intent (parent.getContext(), Record.class);
            intent.putExtra("key", scanList);
        }
```

Then in my next activity in the onCreate have the following:

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
        ET1.setText(value);
```

Comment: If you have some sample code to add, it might be easier to give you a specific answer. Just edit your question and toss it in there. :)

Comment: Hey barett. This is what i'm guessing I know its still a bit far off but I hope you get the point lol.

Answer (score 1):

Following the HUGE help in the comments from Filipe (Thanks again) the following is the solution to the problem:

In my first activity I have the following in my onItemClick for my ListView:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        HashMap<String, String> hashmap = (HashMap)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent (parent.getContext(), SECONDACTIVITY.class);
        intent.putExtra("key", hashmap);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
}
```

In my second activity I then used this piece of code in the onCreate:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle!=null) {
            HashMap<String, String> vals = (HashMap)bundle.getSerializable("key");
            et1.setText(vals.get("value1"));
            et2.setText(vals.get("value2"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the data for the parent adapterview, something like { parent.getItem(position) } and send that through the intent (instead of retrieving all the data from the controller). On the next activity you'd iterate through the hashmap items and set them to the apropriate EditTexts.

**Edit:**
On your `public void onItemClick(...)` you should probably use:

`HashMap<String, String> yourHashMap = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
Intent intent = new Intent (parent.getContext(), Record.class);
intent.putSerializable("key", yourHashMap);`

And on the next activity:

`Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle!=null) {
    HashMap<String, String> vals = (HashMap)bundle.getSerializable("key");
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1)).setText(vals.get("value1"));         ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt2)).setText(vals.get("value2"));        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt3)).setText(vals.get("value3"));
}`

Comment: I'm not familiar with iterating through a hashmap and putting them into edit texts. Would you have an example I could use? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I've just realized you most likely don't need to iterate through them. You can simply access them by key like: 
`HashMap<String, String> vals = getVals();

        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1)).setText(vals.get("value1"));
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt2)).setText(vals.get("value2"));
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt3)).setText(vals.get("value3"));`
@dotexecutable

Comment: But for curiosity sake if you want to iterate through the values you can use:
`for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : vals.entrySet())
        {
            final String key = entry.getKey();
            final String value = entry.getValue();
        }`
@dotexecutable

Comment: So for to use the first reply from you I would use something like; Intent intent = getIntent(); in my second page then your following code? I'm sorry i'm quite new at this and thank you for the help. @Filipe Silvia

Comment: What does it look like inside your AdapterView? I'm assuming you use a custom AdapterView. If the data stored inside it is an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` you would get the `HashMap` using `HashMap<String, String> myHashMap = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);` and then sent that hasmap through the intent. Check the edited answer

Comment: Also, if my last edit does not solve your issue please send through the AdapterView class. =) @dotexecutable

Comment: My onItemClick code looks like this: `public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
   long id) {
  String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
  Toast.makeText(PlateScan.this, "You clicked on:"+item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  
  Intent intent = new Intent (parent.getContext(), Record.class);
  intentv2.putExtra("key", item);
  startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
  
 }`

Comment: My listview adapter looks like this also; `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> scanList = this.controller.getAllRecs();

     myAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, scanList, R.layout.list_view_layout, new String[]{"regNo","streetName","recDate"},
                new int[]{R.id.reg_No,R.id.street_Name,R.id.date_Time});
   Recs.setAdapter(myAdapter);` This is awesome help btw, i've never had a stackoverflow member help me this much before lol. Thank you!

Comment: From your edited answer i'm getting two errors: `parent.getItemAtPosition(position);` come up with the error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to HashMap<String,String>" and the second one under `putSerializable` says "The method putSerializable(String, HashMap<String,String>) is undefined for the type Intent"

Comment: My bad. putSerializable is for Bundle, for intents we use:
`intent.putExtra("key", yourHashMap);`
And as for the `parent.getItemAtPosition(position);` all you need is a cast:
`HashMap<String, String> yourHashMap = (HashMap)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);`@dotexecutable

Comment: Filipe thank you so much! It works like a treat! I can't thank you enough :)

Comment: No problem at all! For the next question try and post as much relevant info as you can in the original question, it can go a long way to help us sort out your issue. =) @dotexecutable oh and also if you can mark it as the answer it'd be great. Cheers

Comment: Yes I will make sure I do and I just answered the question :) Cheers